# What is the API for UNIX like Win 32 API in windows?

Tags: unix, operating-system

What is the API for Unix like Win 32 API in Windows?

Is that POSIX library for Unix?

Answer (score 2):

POSIX is not a library, it's a set of [standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posix). Citation: *POSIX defines the application programming interface (API), along with command line shells and utility interfaces, for software compatible with variants of Unix and other operating systems.* So this is comparable to the Windows API in some way.

Not entirely an answer to your question, but if you want to program under Unix, the book [Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Environment-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Computing/dp/0201433079) is a classic and a very good starting point.